# jQuery selector using data value does not work with programatically assigned values

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, tags

I have a situation where I need to assign certain data values to elements programatically. Everything works good and I can get the value back using `$("#elementId").data("dataname")`. However if I try to fetch multiple items with a certain class and data value using `$(".className[data-dataname='assignedValue']")` it does not work.

I have tried running these commands on Devtools and got `undefined` for `$(".className[data-dataname='assignedValue']").prop("id")` even when I use the value of `assignedValue` that I got from `$("#elementId").data("dataname")`

I have created a dummy snippet explaining my issue and was hoping someone would help me here.
(data1 is programatically assigned and data2 added in html)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

            $(".myDiv").data("data1", "assignedValue1");

            $.each($(".myDiv"), function () {
                console.log($(this).prop("id") + " > fetching value using data1: " + $(this).data("data1"));
            });

            $.each($(".myDiv[data-data1='assignedValue1']"), function () {
                console.log("found something from data1"); //FOUND NOTHING!!
            });

            $.each($(".myDiv[data-data2='assignedValue2']"), function () {
                console.log("found from data2 > id: " + $(this).prop("id"));
            });

            console.log("With data1: " + $(".myDiv[data-data1='assignedValue1']").prop("id"));
            console.log("With data2: " + $(".myDiv[data-data2='assignedValue2']").prop("id"));

        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div id="div1" class="myDiv" data-data2='assignedValue2'>Div1</div>
    <div id="div2" class="myDiv" data-data2='assignedValue2'>Div2</div>
    <div id="div3" class="myDiv" data-data2='assignedValue2'>Div3</div>
    <div id="div4" class="myDiv" data-data2='assignedValue2'>Div4</div>
    <div id="div5" class="myDiv" data-data2='assignedValue2'>Div5</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a common misconception about how `$.data` works in jQuery. [`$.data`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) does not modify the DOM attributes

> Using the data() method to update data does not affect attributes in the DOM. To set a data-* attribute value, use attr.

To solve this, use `$.attr`

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

            $(".myDiv").attr("data-data1", "assignedValue1");

            $.each($(".myDiv"), function () {
                console.log($(this).prop("id") + " > fetching value using data1: " + $(this).data("data1"));
            });

            $.each($(".myDiv[data-data1='assignedValue1']"), function () {
                console.log("found something from data1"); //FOUND NOTHING!!
            });

            $.each($(".myDiv[data-data2='assignedValue2']"), function () {
                console.log("found from data2 > id: " + $(this).prop("id"));
            });

            console.log("With data1: " + $(".myDiv[data-data1='assignedValue1']").prop("id"));
            console.log("With data2: " + $(".myDiv[data-data2='assignedValue2']").prop("id"));

        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div id="div1" class="myDiv" data-data2='assignedValue2'>Div1</div>
    <div id="div2" class="myDiv" data-data2='assignedValue2'>Div2</div>
    <div id="div3" class="myDiv" data-data2='assignedValue2'>Div3</div>
    <div id="div4" class="myDiv" data-data2='assignedValue2'>Div4</div>
    <div id="div5" class="myDiv" data-data2='assignedValue2'>Div5</div>
```